# Writing the formula for maximum likelihood

Tags: symbols

I'm new to latex and i would like to write in latex code the formula for maximum likelihood with the L and lambda in parenthesis. I thought I would find it easily on the internet but no luck. It is the two formulas written below especially the 1 with the contour.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Could you type out some approximation?  What have you tried so far?  Could you give us a sample tex file that gets close?

Comment: There's more than one way to express likelihood functions and hence also more than one way to express maximization over these functions. Could you maybe post a screenshot or a scan of a hand-written formula you'd like to replicate?

Comment: `$L(\lambda) = \Prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} P(X=x_{i})$`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I suppose the O.P. means the `\boxed` command, and maybe the `fleqn` option (or the homonymous environment).

Comment: I just saw your replies , i m sorry i didn t thank you earlier i m pretty knew to this forum also , thanks a lot for the formula .And if i could just ask one more thing for the 2nd formula , how do you do the derivative symbol ?

Comment: The symbol is \partial

Comment: @Bernard: Whether the equation etc. is boxed or not is irrelevant, in my point of view. It's a duplicate and good that it got closed. We got too much of those questions anyway.